# How can I manufacture icons for MacOs from a non-Apple system?

Tags: open-source, image-conversion, icon

I am coding for a Qt based project that runs on multiple OSes; I personally have Windows 10, (Devuan) Linux and FreeBSD to work on and I have managed to make a series of `.png` icons in the sizes (and DPI) listed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703594/4805858 .

However, since I do not have a MacOs computer I do not have the `iconutil` or `sips` utilities (whatever they are?) to assemble these images into `.icns` files, how can I myself this without imposing on a fellow developer with a Hackintosh or an on-line service?

I thought I found an on-line one but its Terms and Conditions made it only available to residents of the United States who are 13 years or older - whilst I am much older than that I live on the wrong side of the Atlantic Ocean (United Kingdom)!

I was hoping for a (free) GIMP plugin or some stand-alone utility that will run on at least one of the OSes that I do have. Does anyone know of anything that can do this compilation/combination/conversion?

*This question has been ported from Stack Overflow on the basis that it was not suitable there (and got speedily closed) but might be answerable here!*